# Windows 8 passing a Stream to a MFSourceReader

Tags: c++, audio, windows-8, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to make a program that can take an .mp3 file from the user's Music Library, and convert it using the Windows Media Foundation's `IMFSourceReader` into an array containing PCM values for some exciting DSP action. However, I'm having problems.

My solution has two projects; a C#/XAML one containing UI code and a C++ Library containing some native code for working with Media Foundation and XAudio2 plus some `public ref` classes which the C# code can interact with.

I can't use `MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL` because it returns an ACCESS DENIED HRESULT even if you have the Music Library capability in the app manifest. So it looks like I'm going to have to use either `MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream` or `MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource`. Now, it's easy enough to access the music file using `Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary` and get a `Stream` or an `IInputStream` along with a few other stream types but how can I convert this to an `IMFByteStream` or an `IMFMediaSource` or just in some way decode the mp3 to a byte array with PCM values?

I have also entertained the idea of resaving the music file in the app folder so that I can use `MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL` or perhaps it would be possible to bypass working with Media Foundation directly and use something like `Windows.Media.Transcoding` to do the conversion to PCM. I'm not sure this is what the Transcoding namespace is for though.

I have spent hours reading through the Media Foundation documentation and I found a glimmer of hope with `MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream` which can convert from COM's `IStream` to a byte stream but I will need to find/write a wrapper to convert my .net stream to an IStream. Before I set off on this task I just want to make sure that I am going in the right direction or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance. Also apologies in advance if I have made a stupid mistake or missed some crucial aspect of working with these libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK everyone, I know you are all clamouring to answer this question but after 2 days of headscratching I have found a solution. You can pass an `Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream^` object to `MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162754(v=vs.85).aspx ) by casting it to `(IUnknown*)` like so:

```
ComPtr<IMFByteStream> spMFByteStream = nullptr; 

MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx((IUnknown*)streamHandle, &spMFByteStream);

//remember to add your own HRESULT error handling code

ComPtr<IMFSourceReader> _sourceReader = nullptr;

MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream(spMFByteStream.Get(),nullptr,&_sourceReader);
```

With `streamHandle` being the `IRandomAcessStream^` that you want to give to the Source Reader.
[Here is a code sample with it running](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Engine-Playback-ce1c82f0)

Time for some toast.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a component out of it (licensed or not), i'd be interested. I am not aware of any component that can transcode a MP4, WMA or M4A audio file to PCM under WinRT. Unfortunately, Windows 8 does not support recording an audio file as PCM.

Comment: From what I've read on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb190307 I'm pretty sure you can record to PCM by using the Media Foundation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317912(v=vs.85).aspx . The first code sample here gets a `IMFMediaSource` from which you can then create a SourceReader by using `MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource`. Once you have a SourceReader you can get the PCM data like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757929(v=vs.85).aspx . I found getting all of this working tricky to say the least.

Comment: Yes it does, through WASAPI; lots of COM calls though.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, complementing the original answer, for those who want to take the route of wrapping a managed stream with a COM `IStream` interface, [here is a good implementation](http://csharpexamples.com/tag/managed-istream/).